# Probability approximation Question

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $S(t)$ be the price of a stock for $t = 0, 1, 2, \dotsc$. Suppose that in each time
period, independently, the price of the stock increases by one unit with probability
0.35, stays the same with probability 0.4 and decreases by one unit with probability
0.25.
Use an appropriate approximation to find the probability that after 500 time periods,
the stock will be at least 10 units higher than where it starts at $t = 0$.

Comment: So far i've gotten E(X) = 0.1 but unsure what to do from there.

Comment: What i did was i approximated to a normal distrubution using np and npq for mean and variation but i dont think this is the right way to go about it.

Comment: To use the normal distribution is a good idea, but we do not have a binomial distribution because we have $3$ possible outcomes. So, I am not sure whether we can take $np$ and $npq$.

Answer (score 1):

I think a normal approximation should work.  If your fluctuation for day $i$ is $X_i$, then $\mu_{X_i}=0.1$ and $\sigma^2_{X_i}=.59$.

Letting $X=\sum_1^{500} X_i$, we have $\mu_X=50$ and $\sigma^2_X=295$.  So $\sigma_X=\sqrt{295}\approx 17.18$.

Then the normal approximation would be $X\approx Y\sim N(\mu=50,\sigma=\sqrt{295})$

You then want $P(Y>9.5)\approx .991$.

I ran a Python simulation of this situation $1000$ times.  For these $1000$ trials, $992$ times the stock went up by at least $10$ units over thf $500$ days.

Comment: I got the same mean and SD of the total change. Simulation in R shows normal approx is OK. Answers closely agree with yours: from simulation with a million 500 time-period sums and by normal aprx.

Comment: Thanks! Amazing stuff, but i'm unsure how you worked out the variance.

Comment: $Var(X_i)=E[X_i^2]-E[X_i]^2=0.6-(0.1)^2=.59$.  And because of independence, $Var(X)=\sum(Var(X_i))=500\cdot(.59)=295$.